# How do I link Office 2013 access tables with ODBC ot my one.com MySQL database server?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I would like to access my one.com MySQL database with ms-Access 2013.

I couldn't make it happen by filling in the below info:
Server: 10.246.16.193 via TCP/IP
Software: MySQL
Software version: 5.1.66-0+squeeze1 - (Debian)
Protocol version: 10
User: ***@phpmyadmin01.local
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Anybody can help me out?

Comment: Normally, mysql databases are closed for access from the outside for security reasons... either way, what error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: You should be able to access a MySQL database from Access using the MySQL ODBC driver, but only if the database hosting server has ports open for you to access it this way. Do also realize that MS Access is not a DB Management tool for MySQL (like Toad). But yes, Access can be used to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE data in MySQL if you get all the pieces of the puzzle put together. Please post what error messages your getting or what problem you are hung up on.